# Unable to use jQuery UI on my Rails project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

Currently I'm using Rails 4 with gem 'jquery-ui-rails', everything seems to be working properly , I have included all necessary depedencies in my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

and also in application.css

```
 *= require jquery-ui
```

There is no error message, but I'm unable to use any jQuery UI components even running a simple jQuery command which `alert(jQuery.ui)` got evaluated to 'undefined'. The weird part is that I can see every jQuery UI javascript files in the header of the rendered HTML page but it seems that I can't use any of them. However I created a new clean Rails project and did the same as above but everything works fine. What should I do with this ?

Comment: try to reload the server

Comment: I tried, and it solves nothing